# In Python, how does flushing work and what is the reason?

Tags: python, printing, buffer, flush

I have a small multithread program including print statement.
It works perfectly if I did not change the `end` to other characters except `\n`.
If I want to use other characters instead of `\n`, I will need to set `flush` to `True`.

So my question is how flushing works and what the reason is?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -u
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
from time import sleep


def do_stuff(task):
    while not task.empty():
        sleep(1)
        print(task.get())  # works well
        # print(task.get(), end='\n')  # works well
        # print(task.get(), end=',', flush=True)  # works well
        # print(task.get(), end=',')  # works badly
        task.task_done()


q = Queue(maxsize=0)
for x in range(0, 5):
    q.put(x)

num_threads = 2

for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=do_stuff, args=(q,))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

q.join()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you print in Python and use as last character a comma (not as character but as separation sign), the output does not get flushed because it is waiting for another print statement. This is the function of the comma in the print command. If you do not add the comma to the print command it should flush and create a new line in the process, actually the other way around, it creates a newline and therefor flushes.

```
    print(task.get(), end=',')
```

Will print without newline and waits for the next print that will create a new line, before flushing the buffer.

```
 print(task.get())  
 print(task.get(), end='\n')  # works well
```

Will print something including a new line and flushes the buffer.

This is very common practice in many console output applications, exactly the same behaviour you get with C and C++. The newline is used as a sign to the buffer to empty, if the buffer would empty after each character it would consume way too much cpu.

```
 print(task.get(), end=',', flush=True)
```

The above works because we say explicitly to flush the buffer. There will be no newline but the print statement will flush the buffer and therefor print immediately.

Comment: Your answer is a bit Py2-centric, whereas OP's code is Py3.

Comment: @BrianO aaah I missed that point. Well the arguments are the same, only the function call is different.. let me update the answer

Comment: In other words, anytime end is equal to anything other than a new line we should use flush=True ?

Comment: @EsdrasLopez if you want to output the text immediately yes, if you do not care much if it get printed later, no.

Comment: @BasvanStein when would you not care if the text gets printed later? Could you share an example?

Comment: @EsdrasLopez I would say almost always, most of the time it does not matter if what you want to print appears a second later on screen. With multiple parallel processes it ussualy does matter because you want it to be printed in a specific order.